# Arrow-head caps on the end of strokes in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I want to have arrowhead caps on the end of a stroke in illustrator (so similar to the rounded caps, but with an arrowhead that fits perfectly to the edge of the stroke)

I can sort of achieve this using actual an arrowhead, but it doesn't look perfect. Here's what I've got so far:

[image]

EDIT:

I've also tried messing with the stroke's Variable Width Profile - there appears to be a profile that is exactly what I'm after, however, the "caps" scale depending on the width of the stroke. I need the arrowheads of the stroke to be exactly at a 45° angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the existing arrowheads from the stroke window, none of them are 45 degrees but #7 looks closest:
[image]

Adjust stroke thickness to get your arrow.

Do you mean you want the stroke to come to a point? Make a right triangle and add it to your arrowhead collection per instructions here:

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1728738

Comment: The link you provided gave me a perfect solution. Thank you kindly!